# SQL Server 2008 SMO not working in C# Namespace Error

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, smo

SQL ServerR2 2008 SMO not working in C# namespace error. I cannot create server object. The references listed in various sites including stackoverflow posts doesn't work for me, please help me.

1st error:

> Reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc is missing

When I add the reference, I get a 2nd error :

> sdk doesn't exists in microsoft.sqlserver.management

Can I upload the source here (I don't see an option)?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;

namespace DatabaseConnectionManagement
{
public partial class FrmAddConnection : Form
{
    ServerConnection m_ServerConnection;
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server m_Server; //Final Error is in this line
    EventHandler _Handler;

    public FrmAddConnection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Server DatabaseServer
    {
        get { return this.m_Server; }
    }

    void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Application was idle and thats when we do the work.
        // Lets first un-register the event.
        Application.Idle -= this._Handler;

        //Check for all the available servers
        DataTable dtServers = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
        dtServers.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtServers.Columns[0] };
        this.cmbServerName.DataSource = dtServers;
        this.cmbServerName.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.cmbServerName.ValueMember = "Name";

        //Set the default server
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.Server))
        {
            this.cmbServerName.SelectedIndex = dtServers.Rows.IndexOf(dtServers.Rows.Find(Properties.Settings.Default.Server.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            this.cmbServerName.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        //What type of authentication the user wants?  We will have to change the string as required.
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.SQLAuthenticationMode)
        {
            this.rdbServerAuthentication.Checked = true;
            this.rdbWindowsAuthentication.Checked = false;

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.SavePassword == true)
            {
                this.txtUserName.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.UserName;
                this.txtPassword.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
                this.chkSavePassword.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.rdbServerAuthentication.Checked = false;
            this.rdbWindowsAuthentication.Checked = true;
            this.txtUserName.Enabled = false;
            this.txtPassword.Enabled = false;
            //this.chkSavePassword.Enabled = false;
        }

        string tmpDbName = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpDbName))
        {
            this.btnTestConnection_Click(this, null);
            this.cmbDbName.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName;
        }
        this.lblSyncStatus.Visible = false;
        this.pnlConnectionInfo.Enabled = true;

    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        this.lblSyncStatus.Visible = true;
        this.lblSyncStatus.BringToFront();
        this.pnlConnectionInfo.Enabled = false;
        // Lets do the work when we've got some time.
        this._Handler = new EventHandler(this.Application_Idle);
        Application.Idle += this._Handler;
    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; 
        DataTable dtServers = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
        this.cmbServerName.DataSource = dtServers;
        this.cmbServerName.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.cmbServerName.ValueMember = "Name";
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    private void ListDatabasesInServer()
    {
        this.cmbDbName.Items.Clear();
        // Loop through the databases list
        foreach (Database db in this.m_Server.Databases)
        {
            //We don't want to be adding the System databases to our list
            //Check if database is system database
            if (!db.IsSystemObject) 
            {
                this.cmbDbName.Items.Add(db.Name); // Add database to combobox
            }
        }
        this.cmbDbName.SelectedIndex = 0;
        //We have the list now
    }

    private void rdbServerAuthentication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtUserName.Enabled = true;
        this.txtPassword.Enabled = true;
        this.chkSavePassword.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void rdbWindowsAuthentication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtUserName.Enabled = false;
        this.txtPassword.Enabled = false;
        //this.chkSavePassword.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btnTestConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; 
        try
        {
            // If a server is selected
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.cmbServerName.Text))
            {
                string message = this.ConnectDatabase();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    //This will populate list of databases on selected server
                    this.ListDatabasesInServer();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(message, "SQL Authetication", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // A server was not selected, show an error message
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a server first", "Server not selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SQL Authetication", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    private string ConnectDatabase()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.cmbServerName.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                this.m_ServerConnection = new ServerConnection(this.cmbServerName.Text.ToString());
                //this.m_ServerConnection
                //First Check type of Authentication
                if (this.rdbWindowsAuthentication.Checked == true)   //Windows Authentication
                {
                    this.m_ServerConnection.LoginSecure = true;
                    this.m_Server = new Server(this.m_ServerConnection);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create a new connection to the selected server name
                    this.m_ServerConnection.LoginSecure = false;
                    this.m_ServerConnection.Login = this.txtUserName.Text;       //Login User
                    this.m_ServerConnection.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;    //Login Password
                    this.m_ServerConnection.DatabaseName = this.cmbDbName.Text;  //Database Name
                    // Create a new SQL Server object using the connection we created
                    this.m_Server = new Server(this.m_ServerConnection);
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
        return "No server selected";
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Server = this.cmbServerName.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.SQLAuthenticationMode = this.rdbServerAuthentication.Checked;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.cmbDbName.Text))
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName = this.cmbDbName.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName = string.Empty;
        }

        if (this.chkSavePassword.Checked)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = this.txtUserName.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.SavePassword = this.chkSavePassword.Checked;
        }
        else
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = string.Empty;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Password = string.Empty;
            Properties.Settings.Default.SavePassword = false;
        }

        string message = ConnectDatabase();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, message, "SQL Authentication",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void cmbServerName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cmbDbName.Items.Clear();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Stupid question: have you ***installed*** the SMO libraries on your machine? If not - [download the `SharedManagementObjects.msi` file as part of the SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27596) and install it

Comment: Solved the problem. Its due to Framework problem. The selected frame work was 2.0 and i changed to 4.0